# what is difference between this two views ? (autorotation)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

http://www.freezpic.com/pics/d63adbfb5faec3ded732dcfee5cc71ef.jpg

in the image one i can enable  red arrows inside the inner square ...

http://www.freezpic.com/pics/736e30ef1accf1d174122f2e1b017b8d.jpg

but in the second image i can't enable red arrows inside the inner square.
why?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it both.. Go to the view properties in the first view and set the status bar as none, then you will be able to do that.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup